# Importing csv file into Cassandra

Tags: csv, cassandra

I am using COPY command to load the data from csv file into Cassandra table . Following error occurs while using the command.

```
**Command** : COPY quote.emp(alt, high,low) FROM 'test1.csv' WITH HEADER= true ;
```

Error is :

```
get_num_processess() takes no keyword argument.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by [CASSANDRA-11574](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11574).  As mentioned in the ticket comments, there is a workaround:

```
Move copyutil.c somewhere else. Same thing if you also have a copyutil.so.
```

You should be able to find these files under `pylib/cqlshlib/`.

Comment: Hi Tyler , I tried the workaround but still there is an error .

Error : global name 'num_processess' is not defined